# Displaying an object in front of another object

Tags: objects, eevee-render-engine, visibility

I have 3 objects. I want one of them to show in front of the first one but not the third one. I don't mind compositing but I prefer without (I am using eevee to render).
[image]

The dotted orange line shows where the red sphere should be visible

Comment: Hello and welcome. why can't u just move it closer to camera until its in front of the small object but still behind the bigger object?

Comment: I'm going to need to use perspective mode and move the camera around.

Comment: why? its not possible to have it display the way u want it unless u move the orange object